How to compute the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt5]$?
I’m reading Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective. On page $284$, it reads

Consider the case where $f(x)=x^2-5$. The ring of all algebraic integers in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt5]$ is $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt5)/2]$, which properly contains $\mathbf Z[\sqrt5]$.

I wonder how to compute “the ring of all algebraic integers in $\mathbf Q[\sqrt5]$”?

@xxxxxxxxx: I don’t see how to get the fraction $(1+\sqrt5)/2$.

What is the minimal polynomial (monic) of $a+b\sqrt{5}$? Note that $\frac{d-1}{4}$ is an integer for $d=5$.
